# MS SQL Server - System Rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedures

We have a looped procedure which does a high volume data processing of transcating, loading and merging two tables using split and merge. During the data processing the system is rolling back the processed data even though there are no explicit rollbacks set up on the procedures.

Are there situations where the SQL Server will automatically rollback these transactions when there is not enough space or if something is wrong with the proc.

There are no validation errors in the procedure or any message while the procedure is executed. The data just disappears.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Do you actually see the process in the rollback state or are you just inferring that?

Comment: Yes. I see the Rollback against the SP'sSPID.

Comment: Yes, there are things that can cause this.  We would need to know a lot more about your procs to figure out what the likely cause is.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server Error log?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. All I got from the logs is this. (@P0 int OUTPUT)EXEC @P0 = Stored Procedure name with  SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH.